# PHP file cannot get $_POST data from index.html

Tags: php, html, post

I'm making a simple email contact form for my website.

this is how the files are structured:

```
---- My_Website
         |
         |__ index.html
         |
         |__ assets
                |
                |__ email.php
```

in the index.html, I have a form with "POST":

```
<form role="form" action="assets/email.php" method="POST">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="sr-only" for="contact-email">Email</label>
                        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email..." class="contact-email form-control" id="contact-email">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="sr-only" for="contact-subject">Subject</label>
                        <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject..." class="contact-subject form-control" id="contact-subject">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="sr-only" for="contact-message">Message</label>
                        <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message..." class="contact-message form-control" id="contact-message"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Send</button>
</form>
```

in my php file, I just did a `var_dump($_POST);` and I'm very sure I write something in the input form, but it it returns me array(0) {}

Comment: Show the php code.

Comment: Change `action="./assets/email.php"` to `action="assets/email.php"`

Comment: var_dump($_POST) is all i have in the php file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `action="./assets/email.php"` to `action="assets/email.php"`

Comment: it still gives me: array(0) { }